# How to track Angular route views and link click through using Piwik

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, matomo

Does anybody have a working example of Piwik integration with an Angular App? I have the following code in mine but only see views of the page and no route views ever show up. I'm new to Angular so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('angularTest', ['ui.utils','ui.bootstrap','ui.router','piwik','ngSanitize', 'ui.highlight']);
```

**Piwik settings**

```
    var _paq = _paq || [];
_paq.push(['trackPageView']);
_paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
function onSuccess(data, request) {
    var spUserData = data.d;
    //get login name
    var loginName = spUserData.LoginName.split('|')[1];
    piwikEmpid = loginName.replace("domain\\","");
    //get display name
    piwikEmpname = spUserData.Title;
    var u="//piwikServer/";
    _paq.push(['setUserId', piwikEmpid]);
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
};
function onError() {
    var u="//piwikServer/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
};
```

**Route menu**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="topTabMenu" data-position="right">
<li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active"><a aria-controls="home" role="tab" ui-sref="home" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackPageView', 'home']);"></a></li>                                              
<li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active"><a aria-controls="home" role="tab" ui-sref="offices" onclick="javascript:_paq.push(['trackPageView', 'offices']);">
Offices</a></li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked on a project with piwik reporting a while ago, to track route changes you can add a `$routeChangeSuccess` listener during your app's `run` cycle:

```
var app = angular.module('angularTest', ['ui.utils','ui.bootstrap','ui.router','piwik','ngSanitize', 'ui.highlight']).
    run(function($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {      

      if(window._paq) {
        window._paq.push(['setCustomUrl', $location.path() ]);
        window._paq.push(['trackPageView']);
      }

    });
  });
```

**EDIT**

If you want to track non-route links, you can write a directive to track link clicks:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('reportPiwik', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

      var href = attributes.href;

      element.on('click', function() {
        if (window._paq) {
          window._paq.push(['setCustomUrl', href]);
          window._paq.push(['trackPageView']);
        }
      });

    }
  };

});
```

And use it in your views like this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" report-piwik>External link</a>
```

Here's a plunkr, I didn't add piwik reporting, but it shows the directive firing the click listener and showing an alert with the href. http://plnkr.co/edit/mMzwY6wz9XhTpTUKuhiU?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. This works. Were you able to catch click throughs on links within the route views? E.g. if somebody clicks through to an external link.

Comment: @freeBSD take a look at my edited answer for external links. hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the following code worked even without including the onclick events attached to the specific states.

```
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {
    if(window._paq){
      window._paq.push(['setCustomUrl', $location.path() ]);
      window._paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    }
  });
```

You can try that too.